# saving in the database variable as ObjectID() MongoDB, NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I created function which is adding people_id inside array of given card. But there is problem that inserted id is always not as an objectId() where I just need it to be saved as objectId.

When id is added to array i I'm sending whole variable board JSON to nodejs API where is executed function findOneAndUpdate. And here is problem because after saved this arrays is not objectID in **Author**. Can someone tell me how to make it?

JSON board

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59e096a7622a3825ac24f343"),
"name" : "1",
"users" : [ 
    ObjectId("59cd114cea98d9326ca1c421")
],
"lists" : [ 
    {
        "list" : "1",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "2",
                "Author" : [ 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d", 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d", 
                    "59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22e"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "3",
                "Author" : []
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "list" : "fea",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "card",
                "Author" : []
            }
        ]
    }
],
"__v" : 0 }
```

Router:

```
 router.post('/add/member', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
  Board.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._id },
    {
      $set: {
          lists : req.body.lists
      }
    },
    {
      upsert: true
    },
    ((cards) => {
      res.send(cards)
    })
  )
});
```

model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var BoardSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, maxlength: 20 },
  lists : { type: Array },
  users : [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Board', BoardSchema);
```

And here is function with adding poeple

```
    $scope.addMemberToCard = (indexList, indexCard, member) => {
    $scope.board.lists[indexList].cards[indexCard].Author.push(member);
    console.log(    $scope.board.lists[indexList].cards[indexCard].Author)

    return ApiService.staff.addMemberToCard($scope.board).then(function () {
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the mongoose Types ObjectID method and then transform the string sent into an ObjectID.

```
const id = new new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(Author);
```

Comment: Hey can you expand the answer, If i send whole board in one json u mean that I have push id to array and next  transform this for string and later this I have to send to mongodb?? Can u more explain about ur answer??

Comment: I don't think I understood your question but I guessed that you are getting a string with an id and you want to save it into the database as an ObjectID. In order to do this, you have to transform the string into an ObjectID using new new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("string"); and then save it into the database.

Comment: Yes all ok but I sending array id's authors for example var Author = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'] and I want this all id to be objectId, Can we do that??

Comment: Yeah, just transform every id into an object id using new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("string");